# Jquery - $(this) id from selector group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, undefined

**So**
I've defined a simple list and an output

```
<div class="item-list">
    <p id="One">First Item</p>
    <p id="Two">Second Item</p>
    <p id="Three">Third Item</p>
</div>

<div class="box">Add Stuff in Here!</div>
```

**And**
I've written this script

```
$(".item-list > p").click(function(){
    var thisId = (this.id);
    $(".box").append('<p>' + thisId + '</p>');  
});
```

**I want**
each item, on click, to append its id as text inside .box element

**Like So**

```
<div class="box>One</div>
```

**And this works**
just like you'd expect. [JS Fiddle of the simplified Working Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Sb3/)

**But in my more complex example:**
the id of the selected element

```
(this.id)
```

comes back as ...

**Ew..**
undefined.

**Here's a JS Fiddle of the more complex version of this:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pQz3W/4/

**What's causing these id's to return undefined?**

To be clear, In the more complex example, I'm doing the same thing, it's just crowded by other functionality. Something in there is causing my id to come back as undefined.

*I'll keep posting updates to this fiddle as I clean the code up more and more to pertain only to what's necessary to be there for this question!*

Comment: you should be able to simplify your 'complex' example to the simplest solution which reproduce your issue. This is one way to debug code

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to do so, and haven't (after a nice 2 hour debug attempt) been able to find any version of my code that doesn't have those ids return undefined. The crazy thing here is that in dev tools, it's clear that the elements do have defined values.

Comment: The ID is returning just fine, but you've failed miserably at looking up stuff in the array.

Comment: I was going to trial and error it but I haven't gotten that far :) And in the js fiddle, the id still seems to not be outputting that ID. And while the code might be buggered up in the fiddle, it's still looking like those ids are showing up as undefined.

Comment: Well, they are defined! Just log them to the console -> http://jsfiddle.net/pQz3W/6/ and you'll see the ID show up, but the array lookup fail. Note that the event handler doesn't work after you've replaced the elements, as it's not delegated.

Comment: You're right. Comments below, that's sorted out. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array

```
ServiceArray = [
    [
        ["SplashPage", "Splash Page", "hey!"],
        ["GamingWebsite", "Gaming Website", "yo!"],
        ["BasicWebsite", "Basic Website", "hi!"],
        ["AdvancedWebsite", "Advanced Website", "ooh!"],
        ["FlexWebsite", "Flex Website", "ahh!"],
        ......etc
```

and you have ID's that you're trying to look up in that array like this

```
var thisId = this.id;
var outputList = ServiceArray[0][thisId][2];
```

but there are no associative arrays in javascript, and the keys you're looking for doesn't exist. You need to rebuild that array with objects that has keys and values that actually match what you're looking for.

Comment: Agreed. `thisId` correctly has the ID of the element. It's the following line that doesn't work: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined` because you don't have a **key** there called `Splash`/`Gaming`/etc

Comment: @Shai - That's the same error I got, and debugging a little more, the array is nowhere close to matching the code used for lookup, as arrays don't even have named keys, just indices.

Comment: Exactly. Probably want `ServiceArray[0]` to be an object, with `Splash`/`Gaming`/etc as keys. The `ServiceArray[0][thisId][2]` would then work unchanged. The rest of your site code may need changing, however. Other option is to add a 4th value, `Splash`, in `ServiceArray[0][0]`, and loop through to find the correct array every time you hover.....

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. Thanks guys! Sorry about that messy script :P

Comment: Waitwaitwait. Hold up

Comment: I'm not using [thisId] and then using [2] as a key. It's a multidimensional array and [0] is calling on the first group, [0][4][2] = "Ahh!"

Comment: Oh oh. Ok I see. I had the right idea, but I was using a text value rather than a numeral. You're right! Perfect.

Comment: Yes, the first list in the array doesn't have numbers as an index, otherwise the idea sound OK

Answer (score 0):

try this: `var thisId = $(this).attr("id");`